# Whether before if

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, conjunctions

"I was wondering whether it's okay **if** I bring this bag with me?"

Whether before if, can I say this, does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

'Whether ... if' is sloppy. Most native speakers would understand what you meant, but a careful speaker might prefer to ask:

"I was wondering whether it's okay to bring this bag?"

We know you want to bring the bag 'with you'.